# Android: How to make button on candidate view in softkeyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, ime, candidate

I want to make candidateView inside button but

you see log cat:

[image]

please share code

My Code 
**SoftKeyboard.java**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateCandidatesView() {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View wordBar = li.inflate(R.layout.wordbar, null);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) wordBar.findViewById(R.id.words);
        Button btn = (Button) wordBar.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        mCandidateView = new CandidateView(this);
        mCandidateView.setService(this);
        setCandidatesViewShown(true);
        mCandidateView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ll.addView(mCandidateView);
        return wordBar;
    }
```

I want to make like this:

[image]

Layout wordBar.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/words"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for advance

Comment: can you show us your layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this line

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) wordBar.findViewById(R.id.words);
```

You are casting a TextView into LinearLayout

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/words"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

`R.id.words` is a TextView

### Solution

Add an id to your LinearLayout

`Example :android:id="@+id/wordsLayout"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/wordsLayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/words"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And use that id

```
 LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) wordBar.findViewById(R.id.wordsLayout);
```