# Add button on CandidateView

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

In my keyboard app, I have created a dynamic candidate view rather than using xml file. On that candidate view, I have to create a button for emojis. My problem is similar to this one :-
[Android: How to make button on candidate view in softkeyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32450743/android-how-to-make-button-on-candidate-view-in-softkeyboard)
But what I don't have is a layout file for CandidateView as I have similar keyboard as that of AndroidSoftKeyboard.
Can anyone tell me how do I create button on that CandidateView in android?

My code of candidate view in SoftKeyboard.java

```
public View onCreateCandidatesView() {
    mCandidateView = new CandidateView(this);
    mCandidateView.setService(this);
    setCandidatesViewShown(true);
    return mCandidateView;
}
```